# Tableau, strange behavior for reference line

Tags: tableau-api

I'm attempting to show the results of an experiment. I'm using a calculated field and a parameter to create the following view, splitting the view by pre and post dates.
The trouble is the "Average" reference line...

[image: Image of my Tableau Desktop]

None of the reference lines are placed at the actual Average for that time period (or any time period, from what I can tell). I know this because when I highlight the full date range the reference line adjusts:

[image]

Here's how I've set up the Average:
[image]

here's the calculation for post-reset (pre-reset is the same). `[ reset-date ]` is a hard coded parameter (the date the intervention began).

```
date( if [Friday Date] >= [reset-date]
then [Friday Date]
end)
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I was helped on the Tableau forum itself:
https://community.tableau.com/message/673000#673000

Instead of creating two date axis, I added one dimension to show pre and post.

See post at the link above for a full description, images, and a reference file.